# How to block scrolling without "jumping"

Tags: css

Well i know about `overflow-y: hidden`, but I dont like that my site "jumps" to the right side like for 20px every time i use `overflow-y: hidden`.

Is it possoble to block scrolling without "jumping"?

here is example http://jsfiddle.net/wjyb8tzw/6/

Comment: Please give us an example, for example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wjyb8tzw/6/

Answer (score 0):

Just give a margin or padding of 20px at the right side.

```
padding-right:20px;
```

Answer (score 0):

The line    overflow-y disables the scrollbar on the right, this changes the maximum width of the webpage.

The line `margin: auto` centers the div based on the maximum width of the webpage, therefore disabling the scrollbar moves the div a little to keep it centered.

If you specifically don't want the div to be centered then use `margin-left: -17px;` as the width of the of the scrollbar is 17 pixels as stated [here](http://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/browser-scrollbar-width.php).